# What's the simplest deploy/rollback scheme for a Rails app stored in CVS and destined for a Linux server?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, cvs

I have a Rails app that is stored in CVS because that is our corporate standard.  It needs to be deployed to a single production server that is running Rails using Apache and Phusion Passenger.

About the production server:

- RedHat Enterprise Linux 5.1
- The app is used internally at our company, not hosted externally.
- I have root access and can install necessary software.
- I have ssh access to the box, and can also run cvs there if needed.

Current Solution:

I have been using a patched version (a couple of CVS fixes) of capistrano for this, but it's overkill.  (I've looked at vlad the deployer, but it does not support CVS.)  I want something simpler, with fewer dependencies/patches.

Desired Solution:

- I want deployment to be a single command that checks out the tip of the CVS tree and deploys it.
- I want rollback to be a single command that reverts to the previously installed version.
- A couple of Rakefile tasks, or a shell script would be fine.
- Releases need to be uniquely identifiable--either via timestamp, CVS tag, or some sort of version number.

Comment: What is wrong with Capistrano? It does all of those things, and if you do not want its extra features, you don't have to use them.

Comment: Keeping all the gems and other "moving parts" in this project upgraded and "in sync" takes time.  I'm looking to reduce dependencies wherever I can.  Capistrano is extra work to maintain/upgrade on multiple development/staging/test boxes, especially since the CVS module requires patches.  (I'd submit the patches to the Capistrano project, but one of them needs work before it's general-purpose.)

Answer (score 3):

Capistrano is the current gold standard for Rails application deployment; if you already have it working, why do you want to change it?

Comment: Because it only works after I manually apply a couple of patches.  I don't want to do that every time I upgrade.  Also, since my situation is so simple, I'm thinking Capistrano could be replaced by a short shell script that means fewer dependencies, less maintenance.

Comment: So instead of manually patching Capistrano for a future update that you might never get to (I mean, no one's even working on it actively!), you'd rather write a custom script now that will also require maintenance if you ever want to change it?  Psh.  Use Capistrano. :)